# Plot many horizontal Bar Plots in the same graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot a x-y function, that shows the histograms at x-values. Something similar to the bottom plot of the next figure:

[image: Set of vertical histograms]

I tried to use matlab's "barh", but can't plot many in the same figure. 
Any ideas?

Or, maybe displacing the origin (baseline, basevalue in barseries properties) of successive plots would work. How could I do that for barh?

thanks.

Comment: I have seen people using `gnuplot` for such needs. www.gnuplot.info/‎

Comment: I have to stay in matlab. Thanks though.

Comment: create a different axes handle for each column. Manually position each one using its `'Position'` property.

Comment: Could you please indicate how to set a new origin for each column using position? Thanks!

Comment: isn't it easier to superimpose imagesc and plot to show the same info?

Comment: Humm, can't follow you on that one... how'd you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `'Position'` of axes property

```
% generate "data"
m = rand( 40,10 ); 
[n x] = hist( m, 50 );

% the actual plotting
figure; 
ma = axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .8] );  % "parent" axes
N = size(n,2);  % number of vertical bars
for ii=1:N, 
   % create an axes inside the parent axes for the ii-the barh
   sa = axes('Position', [0.1+(ii-1)*.8/N, 0.1, .8/N, .8]); % position the ii-th barh
   barh( x, n(:,ii), 'Parent', sa); 
   axis off;
end
```

[image]

Comment: How do you add a title to this? If I try to add a title it shows up in a weird location and if I reset the axes to 'parent axes' my whole plot flies away.

Comment: @frickskit - I really don't have too much experience with this. Maybe post your comment as a question?

Comment: Why did you remove the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I figured out the answer and the answer was trivial and not worth an entry on SO. (I added an edit to this answer)

Comment: I have a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490143/matlab-multiple-bar-plot-constant-height-axes