# Matlab multiple bar plot constant height axes

Tags: matlab

I am using the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380472/plot-many-horizontal-bar-plots-in-the-same-graph/16384795#16384795) and trying to make every set of bars have proportional heights. This method will make a bar of .1 height look the same height as a bar of, say, .5 height on another vertical column... I have tried setting 'XLimMode' to manual and 'XLim' to constant values, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to assure that all the bar charts have heights proportional to the SAME 'y'-axis (height-of-bar axis)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, first find the maximum of all your values (`totmaxaxes`) and then add the line right before `axes off`.

```
totmaxaxes = max(n(:));

% generate "data"
m = rand( 40,10 ); 
[n x] = hist( m, 50 );

% the actual plotting
figure; 
ma = axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .8] );  % "parent" axes
N = size(n,2);  % number of vertical bars
for ii=1:N, 
   % create an axes inside the parent axes for the ii-the barh
   sa = axes('Position', [0.1+(ii-1)*.8/N, 0.1, .8/N, .8]); % position the ii-th barh
   barh( x, n(:,ii), 'Parent', sa); 
   set(sa, 'Xlim', [0,totmaxaxes + totmaxaxes/40])      %ADD THIS! (+ totmaxaxes/4 just assures that your bar doesn't hit the top)
   axis off;
end
```