# Using separate BaseValues / BaseLines for MATLAB bar and barh plots?

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to plot more than one `bar` or `barh` on the same axes, using a different `BaseValue` for each?

When I try to set the `BaseValue` property of the second bar graph, it changes the `BaseValue` for the first bar graph as well! See the example below.

A solution using multiple axes is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380472/plot-many-horizontal-bar-plots-in-the-same-graph), but can it be done without the creating additional axes? Specifically I'd like to set the `BaseValue` in relation to other data I'm plotting, so overlaying another axes isn't practical since I can't (or I don't know how to?) refer to the coordinates from the original axes.

```
subplot(1,3,1); 
bar(1:10,'BaseValue',5,'FaceColor','b');
hold on; plot([0 11],[5 5],'k-','LineWidth',2); 
         plot([0 11],[15 15],'k-','LineWidth',2); axis([0 11 0 21]);

subplot(1,3,2); 
bar(11:20,'BaseValue',15,'FaceColor','r');
hold on; plot([0 11],[5 5],'k-','LineWidth',2); 
         plot([0 11],[15 15],'k-','LineWidth',2); axis([0 11 0 21]);

subplot(1,3,3); 
bar(1:10,'BaseValue',5,'FaceColor','b'); hold on;
bar(11:20,'BaseValue',15,'FaceColor','r');
    plot([0 11],[5 5],'k-','LineWidth',2); 
    plot([0 11],[15 15],'k-','LineWidth',2);axis([0 11 0 21]);
```

Comment: This appears to be a change that showed up in a recent matlab update, as it performs as desired in 2013a, but gives "broken" behavior in R2014b.  The behavior appears to be semi-intentional, as the `Bar` objects each have a `BaseLine` property, which is read-only, and appears to always match among all bar graph objects in a given axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a change that showed up in a recent matlab update, as it performs as desired in 2013a, but not in 2014b.  This is presumably due to the switch to HG2 graphics, and seems to be quasi-intentional.  `Bar` objects returned by `bar(...)` have a `BaseLine` property that is read-only.  You can adjust properties of the `Baseline` object, and you can even copy them, but there appears to be only one per axis (axes object property `YBaseline` for example).

To work around this in the new version, you can use the `'hist'` style flag, which causes `bar()` to create a patch object rather than a bar graph object:

```
h(1) = bar(1:10, 'hist', 'b', 'BaseValue',5); hold on;
h(2) = bar(11:20,'hist', 'r', 'BaseValue',15);
```

As the resulting objects are not `Bar` objects, they are not affected by the parent axes' `YBaseline` property, but neither can you change the properties in a standard way as you can with `Bar` objects.

(This is the state in Matlab R2014b; I'm not sure what changes R2015a may have brought...)

Comment: I just updated to MATLAB R2015b and this solution no longer works! It seems like using the `hist` style now ignores the `BaseValue` specification... arrrgh...

Comment: Even just one call `bar(1:10, 'hist', 'b', 'BaseValue', 5);` doesn't appropriately adjust the `BaseValue`

Comment: Sorry, I'm no help; our software distribution is stuck at 2014b.  If you haven't done so already, worth a try at submitting a bug report to the mathworks.

Comment: PS. What I did before was to read through `bar.m` and found that it had some options listed that got you a legacy style plot (`patch` object instead of a `Bar` object).  You could look through and see if that's still true.